# Problema de configuración de sesión persistente en Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Estoy intentando configurar **Tomcat 8.5.9** para que arranque en modo de sesión persistente y almacene la sesión en MySql. Para ello he seguido el procedimiento descrito en la [documentación de Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html):

1. Crear la tabla tomcat_sessions, tal como indican en la documentación:

> ```
> create table tomcat_sessions (
>   session_id     varchar(100) not null primary key,
>   valid_session  char(1) not null,
>   max_inactive   int not null,
>   last_access    bigint not null,
>   app_name       varchar(255),
>   session_data   mediumblob,
>   KEY kapp_name(app_name)
> );
> ```

2. En segundo lugar, he introducido la librería **mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar** en el classpath de tomcat.
3. Finalmente he modificado el fichero context.xml del siguiente modo:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context>
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
       <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

       <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"     
       debug="0"
       maxActiveSessions="-1"
       maxIdleBackup="-1"
       minIdleSwap="-1"
       maxIdleSwap="-1"
       processExpiresFrequency="1"
       saveOnRestart='true'
       >

           <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore"        
               connectionName="root"
               connectionPassword="password"
               connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tomcat"
               driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               />
   </Manager>
   </Context>
   ```

Cuando ejecuto Tomcat, salta el siguiente error:

```
16-Jan-2017 11:55:04.597 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal The session manager failed to start
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager[/manager]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5206)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore[org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager[/manager]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManagerBase.startInternal(PersistentManagerBase.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.open(JDBCStore.java:906)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.getConnection(JDBCStore.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore.startInternal(JDBCStore.java:1001)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun el código fuente, la linea 906 donde tienes el NullPointer es la que setea el autocommit:

```
   // Open a new connection
    Properties props = new Properties();
    if (connectionName != null)
        props.put("user", connectionName);
    if (connectionPassword != null)
        props.put("password", connectionPassword);
    dbConnection = driver.connect(connectionURL, props);
    dbConnection.setAutoCommit(true);
    return dbConnection;
```

Por lo tanto, parece que el Driver lo está encontrando bien, pero no puede crear la conexión. Asegúrate de que la url de conexión, el puerto, el usuario y el passwd son correctos.

Comment: Exacto, había un fallo en la cadena de conexión.